# Topic Synonyms in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

Sometimes, I'll search for something in Documentation to find that the topic is under a different name. On SO, this is solved by using tag synonyms, so closely related tags are associated with each other.

I propose creating topic synonyms on Documentation, so topics which may be referred to by multiple names can be easily searched for and found.

Quick mockup:

[image: Topic synonyms]

A few points about this:

- These can be edited through the draft system. A change can be approved or rejected as normal.
- When merging a topic, the name of the old topic can be (automatically?) made a synonym of the new topic.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an excellent idea, although there should not be matching synonyms for different topics. They have synonyms with tags, do they not? Why not have it with docs? Overall, this proposal is excellent.